# how to make a hidden view in uitableview using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05fGP.gif)

the given gif, it starts with a table view, if you swipe down you can see a bar with a slider inside? and you release the finger it will hide again.
How do I implement something similar?

Comment: Perhaps it's the table's header view along with an adjust content inset.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a customised pull-to-refresh control. See [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirefreshcontrol) for more info on Apple's own UIRefreshControl. There are also libraries that you could choose to use instead of UIRefreshControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra cell on the top / header. Then you set the content offset in the scroll view of UITableView equal to the height of that cell / header.